# How to stop joint pose from being completely ignored by Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What are the rules by which Gazebo interprets joint poses? They seem completely different from links.

I have a two simple "bars", representing parts of a leg, each rotated by 45 degrees to form a "knee" at their intersection:

```
<link name="upper">
    <pose>-.01 .035 .1 0 0 0.785398</pose>
    <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 -0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <inertia>
            <ixx>0.01</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.01</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.01</izz>
        </inertia>
        <mass>10.0</mass>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
            <box>
                <size>0.04 0.005 0.003</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
            <box>
                <size>0.04 0.005 0.003</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
            <script>Gazebo/Purple</script>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>
<link name="middle">
    <pose>0 0 .097 0 0 -0.785398</pose>
    <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 -0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <inertia>
            <ixx>0.01</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.01</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.01</izz>
        </inertia>
        <mass>10.0</mass>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
            <box>
                <size>0.07 0.005 0.003</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
            <box>
                <size>0.07 0.005 0.003</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
            <script>Gazebo/Blue</script>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>
```

I want to attach a revolute joint at the intersection, representing the knee joint. So I thought  the joint's pose would be identical to the point at the end of the bar. This point is calculated as the half the length of the bar, minus an inset, rotated about the origin by 45 degrees, which is the x/y coordinate of (-0.0229809703886, 0.0229809703886).

This gives me a joint with a pose like:

```
<joint name="upper_middle_joint" type="revolute">
    <pose>-0.0229809703886 0.0229809703886 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <child>middle</child>
    <parent>upper</parent>
    <axis>
        <limit>
            <lower>-0.4</lower>
            <upper>0.4</upper>
        </limit>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
    </axis>
</joint>
```

However, when I view this in Gazebo, it looks like:

```
![joint misalignment](http://i.imgur.com/rwkXhUz.png)
```

Instead of posing the joint up along the y-axis by 0.023 and over along the negative x-axis by 0.023, it appears to have moved the joint up along the y-axis by 0.04 and nothing along the x-axis.

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8424/how-to-stop-joint-pose-from-being-completely-ignored-by-gazebo/) by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

According to the SDF [specification](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=joint#joint_pose), the joint pose is the "*Pose offset from child link frame to joint frame (expressed in child link frame)*".

Note that the axis of rotation can be expressed in the joint frame or the parent model frame, using the [`<use_parent_model_frame>`](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=joint#axis_use_parent_model_frame) tag.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on 2015-04-11**:
Ah, that makes sense. My "middle" link is rotated by 45 degrees, and the joint automatically is as well, so I didn't need to add any additional rotation. However, how is that `use_parent_model_frame` tag used? Those docs don't say, and specifying true or false for it doesn't seem to have any effect.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2015-04-12**:
`use_parent_model_frame` only changes the frame used to interpret the axis xyz tag, not the  joint pose tag. It's really there for backwards compatibility (see [gazebo issue 494](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/494) for historical reference).